# git - support for symlinks in git commands (as IntelliJ needs it)

Tags: git, unix, intellij-idea, symlink

I use Linux so I have no problems with storing symlinks in git repository. But I have problem with commands with symlinks. I have files tree like following:

```
.
├── Module
│   └── file.txt
└── Project
    └── Module -> /full/path/to/repository/Module
```

When I try to execute any git command I get an error, for example:

```
git blame Project/Module/file.txt
fatal: no such path 'Project/Module/file.txt' in HEAD
```

Is there a way to force git to support that correctly? I am asking because in IntelliJ when I want to *annotate* file (right click on left bar) it shows me an error as my project uses symlinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git doesn't track content hidden behind a symlink.  It'll track what's in  the symlink, the path you stored, but if you want it to talk to git about what's at that path you'll have to use its path directly.

Comment: So maybe IntelliJ can handle this itself? This is not solution to my problem.

Comment: I will accept your answer but please update it - IntelliJ is planning to add support for git files after symlinks with this future:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-139788

Comment: Well, let's wait and see if they actually implement this.